# Media Queries not being read by mobile devices

Tags: html, css, media-queries

So I have a responsive site I'm working on, which displays fine when I'm viewing it on my computer. As I resize the browser in Chrome, IE, Safari..etc, the site responds to the media queries I've declared in the css document. However, when I'm viewing the site on an iPhone, iPad or any other mobile device, the media queries aren't being detected and it's showing the scaled down version of the desktop breakpoint. Additionally, i have a Chrome extension that detects media queries in sites, and it says there's no media queries detected on my site.

I do have

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

in the head tag and my media query in my css looks like this.

```
@media  screen and (max-width : 620px) {
ul.mainmenu {display:none;} 
footer {height:140px;}
}
```

Mobile devices only seem to respond to "max-device-witdth" but not "max-width" And while that's fine for me to just duplicate the media queries with "max-device-width", the rest of the elements that aren't specified in the media query still displays as a scaled down desktop view. Any ideas?

Comment: Does your CSS validate?

Comment: Yeah I ran the CSS through a validator and it didn't detect any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer to my question,but I figured out what was going on. The site is hosted on GoDaddy with a virtual domain name. so I'd been accessing it at vanityname.domain.com. When I hit that site on my phone, or on desktop, for some reason the HTML5 document is loading as a HTML 4 document. However, if I go to www.domain.com/vanityname, the site shows as a HTML5 document. Not sure at all the reasoning behind that, but would have saved me hours of frustration...